# What is the definition of "Node Failure" in Hadoop?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

Can a faulty node transfer data although it cannot be part of the computation?

Comment: I wonder why this question is down voted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A node failure can be anything from "the daemon doesn't respond" to "the whole rack went down".

> Can a faulty node transfer data although it cannot be part of the computation?

Yes a datanode can serve data, even if it is flagged as down. The reason is that sometimes heartbeats from the datanode to the namenode are delayed and thus the namenode will flag a datanode as dead. However, even if a datanode is considered dead, it can still serve the blocks that were requested before it transitioned into a dead state.

This also applies for local short-circuit reads that do not contact the datanode, but rather read their blocks from disk directly.

Comment: So, you are saying until the datanode is pronounced dead, it'll serve as blocks and not after that, right? And, for the second part of you the answer, you mean though the datanode is dead, the local blk files would still be there and can be read locally?

Comment: @JtheRocker read carefully. If a datanode is alive (to the namenode) it can get requests from the namenode that resolves the file to block mapping. But beeing dead to the namenode doesn't mean that it isn't currently serving a block to a client elsewhere.

Comment: OK - let me confirm this with you. Say for an instance blocks A and B were being served by a datanode prior to it being flagged dead by the namenode. So, will it continue serving those blocks after it's dead? Thanks for your patience.

Comment: @SSaikia_JtheRocker exactly, the datanode will not know that it is dead. Thus still serving the blocks. If the datanode goes down so it can not serve the block, it will cause a timeout or interrupt in the reader- which then will consult the namenode for another location.

Comment: That make sense but do you have any source from where you got to know this? Or it's just that you can tell from the practical experience/experiments or source code?

Comment: @SSaikia_JtheRocker that's how the architecture works. Majorly source code, partly experience (in case of traffic peaks heartbeats get lost easily- but you can tell from the task logs/tcpdump that they are still streaming data despite dead for the namenode). I guess you can setup an environment to prove this, e.g. with small heartbeat timeouts, a sleep job and another job that generates lots of network traffic.

Comment: Gotcha! Will do that experiment sometime when I get free time. Thanks buddy for the awesome input.